# Is local-homotopy instead of local-homeomorphism in fiber bundles sufficient to conclude homotopy equivalence?

Tags: general-topology

I read on Wikipedia [1] the following:
For every fiber bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow B$ with fibers homotopy equivalent to a point it holds that $E$ and $B$ are homotopy-equivalent.
The definition of fiber bundles can be read in [2].
Specifically, for every point, the fiber must be homeomorphic to the fiber $F$.
In my application, I only have homotopy-equivalence to $F$.
To be more specific $\pi^{-1}(b)$ is always homotopy-equivalent to a point, but it may sometimes be an interval and sometimes a square and so on.

Unfortunately, it is not clear to me from Wikipedia, where I can read this up in a primary source like a textbook. Also, it is a little confusing as [1] states that homotopy-equivalence to a point is enough. Whereas, [2] states that we need a homeomorphism locally.

**Question:** If $\pi: E\rightarrow B$ is subjective, and continuous and $\pi^{-1}(b)$ is always
homotopy-equivalent to a point, can I conclude that $E$ and $B$ are homotopy-equivalent?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle

Comment: Sounds like you may be interested in the concept of a fibration.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but, without assuming any good topological relation between nearby fibers (as is assumed in the definition of a fiber bundle), I would not be surprised if there was a counterexample.